# PDF of XY and Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

This is what I've done so far

[image]

Not sure what to do for b)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please use Jax to post your question rather than posting a 'picture of it')  Mostly it will be easy. In order to get $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ you need to type `$X \sim \Gamma(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$`.  (The `$` signs indicate entering and leaving 'math' mode.) // The question suggests a transformation that will lead to the distribution of $XY.$ Can you show how to start that? Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) under Gamma.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

a. Close.  $\tfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d~z}(\tfrac zy)=\tfrac 1y$ when $y$ is relatively constant (as it is when bound to the integral). $$\begin{align}f_{XY}(z) &=\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d z}\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{z/y} f_{X}(x)~f_{Y}(y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y&:&y\in(0;\infty)\\[3ex] &= \int_0^\infty \left\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d z/y}{\mathrm d z}\right\rvert~f_X(z/y)~f_Y(y)~\mathrm d y\\[3ex]&=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{f_X(z/y)~f_Y(y)}{y}~\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

---

b. When $W\sim\mathcal\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ then $f_W(w)=\dfrac{\beta^\alpha~w^{\alpha-1}~\mathrm e^{-\beta w}}{\Gamma(a)}~\mathbf 1_{w\in(0;\infty)}$  so what are $f_X(z/y)$ and $f_Y(y)$ ?